# Athena/Presto: unnesting list of objects from serialized JSON string

Tags: sql, arrays, json, presto, trino

My Athena/Presto database has a serialized JSON object, which I am having a difficulty to handle.
Here is an example of the data:

```
WITH input AS (
    SELECT JSON_PARSE('"[{\"is_flag\": 0, \"url\": \"https://app.com/123\"},{\"is_flag\": 1, \"url\": \"https://app.com/456\"}]"') AS json_obj
)

SELECT typeof(x),
    x

FROM
    (input) AS t(x)
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST (CAST(x AS ARRAY<JSON>)) AS u(y)
```

the error message says:

> INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(json). Expected a json array, but got [{"is_flag": 0, "url": "https://app.com/123"},{"is_flag": 1, "url": "https://app.com/456"}] "[{"is_flag": 0, "url": "https://app.com/123"},{"is_flag": 1, "url": "https://app.com/456"}]"

While what I eventually interested in is a table as below:

| is_flag | url |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | https://app.com/123 |
| 1 | https://app.com/456 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is actually double encoded one (i.e. it is a json string containing encoded json), so you need to double decode it with second `json_parse` (note that I use succinct syntax for `unnest`):

```sql
WITH input AS (
    SELECT JSON_PARSE('"[{\"is_flag\": 0, \"url\": \"https://app.com/123\"},{\"is_flag\": 1, \"url\": \"https://app.com/456\"}]"') AS json_obj
)

-- query
SELECT json_extract_scalar(obj, '$.is_flag') is_flag,
       json_extract_scalar(obj, '$.url') url
FROM input,
unnest(cast(json_parse(cast(json_obj as varchar)) as array(json))) as t(obj);
```

Output:

| is_flag | url |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [https://app.com/123|](https://app.com/123%7C) |
| 1 | [https://app.com/456|](https://app.com/456%7C) |